# Tracking in-app billing with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, firebase-analytics

After adding Firebase Analytics to my iOS and Android app the revenue of the iOS in-app purchases are automatically tracked in Firebase, but the Android in-app purchases are not.

Do I have to write extra code for the Android version?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No extra code is necessary.

You need to link your Firebase app to Google Play in order for those in-app purchases to be reported in Firebase Analytics.  You can do so in the Firebase Project Settings->Account Linking section.

Comment: Linked it now, but it says 'Your project has no apps linked to Google Play'. Would that be a problem? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: You need to be the owner of the app on Google Play in order to link it.

Comment: I am. But I think I fixed it by adding the SHA-1. Time to wait until the data is updated to see if it worked.

Comment: Adding the SHA-1 caused the purchases to show up. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue with mine. We had the link, SHA-1 fingerprint but it is still not linking.

Comment: Just want to share that we've had this issue for a few months. We've removed and re-added the SHA-1 with no luck. Our current status is waiting for Firebase Engineering to look into it, after our issue was handled by level one support as much as they could without a resolution.

Comment: Did the support lead to any solution?